# Rabbit breeding

Tags: rabbits, breeding

Can I breed my doe rabbit with one buck to get ovulation started then with  a different buck to finish the process?  I have a buck that wouldn't for what ever reason breed the 2nd time

Comment: One time probably did the trick.  You should know in 28 days. I think this question desires a detailed answer about why or why not multiple breeding/mountings might be good or bad.